# Using ACM or arXiv based tags

Tags: discussion, tags

Should we use tags based one of these subject classifications? IF yes, which one?

1. [The 1998 ACM Computing Classification System](http://www.acm.org/about/class/1998) ([here](http://www.acm.org/about/class/ccs98-html))
2. [arXiv](http://arxiv.org/corr/home) ([here](http://arxiv.org/corr/subjectclasses))

Comment: also [How to Use the Computing Classification System](http://www.acm.org/about/class/how-to-use)

Answer (score 5):

If we use a tag classification at all, we should follow [Theoretical Computer Science](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/), which often uses [arXiv tags](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/455/using-at-least-one-top-level-arxiv-tag) [without the toplevel prefix](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118/proposal-remove-discipline-prefix-from-the-arxiv-style-tags).

I'm only lukewarm with using these tags, because a lot of posters won't be familiar with them and so will not use them. If we do encourage arXiv tags, there'll have to be a tag police (it's certainly doable, I've been the tag police on other sites, but someone has to do it).

Answer (score 1):

Enforcing a particular standard is probably impossible so I think we should just wait and see what we get. We can always edit/retag.

Managing duplicates will be a major concern, I guess.

Comment: Enforcing a standard is possible, but there have to be enough motivated and coordinated people to relentlessly retag every new posts for at least the first year or so (that's my estimate for how long it takes until there are enough people who apply the rules naturally so you don't have to keep watching every new post).